# Issue With importing Cory's collisiondetectionkit

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, installation, adobe

I have trouble getting Cory's Collisiondetectionkit to work. I have installed it, and put the `com` folder in a random folder where I keep all my files. It looks like this:

[image]

**but** I get an error when I export the code below (along with a bit more code)

```
Call to a possibly undefined method checkCollisions 
through a reference with static type Class
```

This is referring to the lines that says

```
if(CollisionLis...
```

below.

This is the code which I have imported it with:

```
import com.coreyoneil.collision.*;
```

and this is where I call it in the code:

```
if(oCharUse == true){
    if(CollisionList.checkCollisions(b1, oChar) == true){
        trace("collision")

}
```

The folder the `com` folder is located in looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Are you missing a closing semicolon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using it wrong.  The function will create an array of DisplayObjects that are colliding.  For example, if `b1` and `oChar` are colliding, `trace(CollisionList.checkCollisions()[0].name);` should trace `b1` and `trace(CollisionList.checkCollisions()[1].name);` should trace `oChar`.

With what you're trying to achieve, you could replace

```
if(CollisionList.checkCollisions(b1, oChar) == true){
```

with

```
if(CollisionList.checkCollisions().indexOf(b1) && CollisionList.checkCollisions().indexOf(oChar)){
```

Source: https://code.google.com/p/collisiondetectionkit/

Comment: Thanks! Although now I get another error: Call to a possibly undefined method checkCollisions through a reference with static type Class.

Comment: @user2789610 Please accept my answer if this helps - at the beginning of your code put `var _collisionList:CollisionList;` and wherever you put `CollisionList` replace it with `_collisionList`.

Comment: This fixes the compiler errors, but now when entering the frame I get this pop-up: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.  at [PROJECTNAME]::MainTimeline/loop()[[PROJECTNAME].MainTimeline::frame3:46]

Comment: @user2789610 Call `removeEventListener` on the `Enter_Frame Event` (I'm guessing, or whatever it is) the code that goes to the third frame is in.  It is assuming `b1` and `oChar` still exist.  Either that or change `if(CollisionList.checkCollisions().indexOf(b1) && CollisionList.checkCollisions().indexOf(oChar)){
if(CollisionList.checkCollisions(b1, oChar) == true){
        trace("collision")
     }
}` to `if(b1 != null && oChar != null) { if(CollisionList.checkCollisions(b1, oChar) == true){
        trace("collision")
     }}
}`

Comment: the second one does not work. bout the first one: What event listener should be removing?

Comment: What function is `if(CollisionList.checkCollisions().indexOf(b1) && CollisionList.checkCollisions().indexOf(oChar))` in?

Comment: its in the ENER_FRAME event loop

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44560/discussion-between-user2789610-and-man-of-snow)